# Write to file is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, filewriter

I have been trying to write to a file in Android. It is not working and it doesn't even create a file. It always executes the catch block. Here is the part of my program.

```
private void write(){
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter  = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AndroidStudioProjects\\SunCalculator\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\au_locations.txt");
        Log.e("Data","path detected");
        BufferedWriter bfWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        bfWriter.write("Text Data");
        bfWriter.close();
        Log.e("Data","worked");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Data","not worked");
    }
}
```

I also tried to  create a `File` object and passing it to the `FileWriter`  constructor. None of these worked. I am using Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: The questions are: from where do you execute this code, what is error message and is `C:\Users\Administrator` is write-enabled.

Comment: Your Android device/emulator does not have a C: drive. Furthermore, you can't write to resources at runtime, if that's actually what you're attempting.

Comment: You must be getting some exceptions and posting it here would surely help.

Comment: I also tried to write to D:\. It also did not work.  My project path is C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\SunCalculator

Comment: Those drives/paths only exist on your development machine. They will not exist on an Android system.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. I think now I can understand. But I read a file perfectly from the C: drive. How is that possible when I cannot write to resources at runtime?

Comment: If that code is in an Android app, running on an Android device or emulator, then I would have to say that you're not really reading a file from the C: drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write a file in location `C:\\Users....` which is the directory structure of Windows OS.

But Android is built upon Linux OS. To get the user writeable directory in android, you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` as below:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
```